# WPF One resource for one element?

Tags: wpf

Does one Resource item can be used only for one element at the same time?
For instance:

[xaml]

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="DockImage" Source="ico/pin.gif"/>
    <Image x:Key="UndockImage" Source="ico/pinHorizontal.gif"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and buttons:

```
<Button Width="26" Name="solutionButton" Click="eventname">
       <DynamicResource ResourceKey="DockImage"/>
 </Button>
<Button Width="26" Name="soundButton" Click="eventname2">
       <DynamicResource ResourceKey="DockImage"/>
 </Button>
```

Their images changes to UndockImage on runtime, but Image is showed only on one of these buttons.
I can multiply Image keys for both DockImage and UndockImage but I assume this will take 2x more memory. Does one resource key can be used for one object (at the same time) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything deriving from `UIElement` can only be shown at one place at a time. You shouldn't define `Image` resources directly, which is the control used to show images. Instead, use some `ImageSource`-derived class, such as `BitmapImage`, which represents an image in memory.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <BitmapImage x:Key="DockImage" UriSource="ico/pin.gif"/>
  <BitmapImage x:Key="UndockImage" UriSource="ico/pinHorizontal.gif"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Width="26" Name="solutionButton" Click="eventname">
  <Image Source="{StaticResource DockImage}"/>
</Button>
<Button Width="26" Name="soundButton" Click="eventname2">
  <Image Source="{StaticResource DockImage}"/>
</Button>
```